# Get locations search: Show all markers by default

Tags: location, google-maps

I played around with the [get locations](https://drupal.org/project/getlocations) module for drupal escpecially with the `get locations search` part.

Finally I got the thing working but I'm wondering now if it's possible to display by default all markers on the map and not only the result markers after a search.

A blank map till I searched something is very confusing to the user.

Thx for any advice in advance.

**EDIT**

Okay I try to write a patch on my own. My research is based on version `7.x-1.10` The essential part ist to load the lat/longs of the location nodes and also the min- / maxes into the array in `getlocations_search.module` line `290:291` which is

```
$minmaxes = '';
$latlons = array();
```

For the "normal" map they are loaded in the function `getlocations_nids()` on line `828` in the file `getlocations.module`.

Comment: If there is no configuration option for that, it probably should be a [feature request in module's issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/getlocations), not a question here.

Comment: Okay I made a feature request -> https://drupal.org/node/2139067. Can you (or someone else) please help me to achieve what I want? By creating a new module based on `Get Locations` with basicaly the method `getlocations_search()` but with my changes. Don't know what I've to change that all markers show by default.

Comment: Why this question is tagges as 'google-maps'?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Open [layers Module](https://drupal.org/project/openlayers) which has an option for adding multiple locations n single map...

**OpenLayers:**

> The OpenLayers core code stores map's object configurations: maps, layers, styles, sources, controls, interactions and components. It combines them to create maps using the [OpenLayers JavaScript library](http://ol3js.org/) on any Drupal site.